# Fujitsu Lifebook E556 wont exit sleep mode after keypresses on keyboard

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, bios, sleep

I'm currently experiencing an issue regarding this notebook. I've tried every little trick in the book to get it to wake up from sleep mode after hitting a key on my keyboard. The only thing I wasn't able to test was setting the BIOS wake up events for keyboard/mouse, since I was unable to find that option in this particular BIOS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Most laptops do not respond to "any key" to wake up the machine and I cannot find anything different about the Lifebook E556.

You can wake it up by opening the lid (if the lid was closed) or pressing the power button if the lid was open.

This should work just fine.

You can use Software to wake up a computer and I have used Software before (Nirsoft) but it is much less convenient than just pressing the power button. However this may work for you the way you are using the computer.

[Software to wake up computer](https://www.pcwdld.com/free-wake-on-lan-tools)

Also try the software here. There is a lot here to post but I can address questions if you have some.

[Wake up from Standby](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/automatically-wake-up-from-windows-stand-by-and-hibernation/)

Comment: yes that does work of course, however since i use my laptop as sort of a PC with a hooked up monitor and keyboard and keep the laptop shut all the time while still running i would like to find a way to wake it up from sleep mode independently of the laptops lid/power button. is there any way to get that to work? maybe through a downloadable software if nothing else works?

Comment: You need to use the way the computer works because most users would not want the computer to wake up with any random key. So that will not work. I added a software link for you.

Comment: thanks for your help, sadly i do not wish to wake my computer on lan. i would simple want to hit a key on my keyboard to wake the computer back up since its way easier for me than getting my laptop out first and having to hit the power button. i tried wake up from standby however that software goes after time and not specific button presses to wake up the computer which is also not what im looking for

Comment: For Keyboard, what I offered is the only way. No "any key" option. For software, there is a second link of waking up from standby software. I understand when you say  "Not from LAN" but did you try offerings from the second link. Otherwise you must use Keyboard prescribed method.